# flex mobile: remove custom components from memory

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm profiling a flex mobile application and I notice that custom MXML elements are never removed from memory while I push and pop views. 
On views remove event i call `removeAllElement()` and `removeChildren()` but it doesn't help.
How can i remove those elements from memory? I have to remove also the listeners created via MXML (es. on a button when I set the `click=""` property)?

Comment: Provide weak references to eventListeners().

Comment: Aren't these components stored in variables that are still available from outside your view?

Comment: I don't know, I think it's impossible to retrieve the instance of components added to a view via mxml code from outside the view (and after the view is popped). I just notice that the number of instances of these components is always increasing: it seems they're never destroyed